# How to find process by exact command?

Tags: shell, ps

This is the list of my processes:

```
$ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 bash -c cp -R /docker /var/lib; echo Loading...; wrapdocker
    7 root      0:00 bash --login
  312 root      0:00 dockerd
  321 root      0:00 containerd --config /var/run/docker/containerd/containerd.toml --log-level info
  488 root      0:00 ps
```

I want to check if the process `dockerd` is running.
When I run: `ps | grep dockerd` it prints two processes:

```
$ ps | grep 'dockerd'
  312 root      0:00 dockerd
  492 root      0:00 grep dockerd
```

I need to find it by the specific command line which is `dockerd` and not `grep dockerd`.

I need it as part of a shell script to check if `dockerd` is running.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `pgrep process` instead of `ps aux | grep process`.

Like, currently `gnome-terminal` is running, so

```
ps aux | grep gnome-terminal
user    2045  0.9  0.9 459456 36084 ?        Ssl  17:33   0:00 
/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
user    2206  0.0  0.0  12780   996 pts/0    S+   17:33   0:00 grep 
gnome-terminal
```

Where as

```
pgrep gnome-terminal
2045
```

And currently chome is not running, so

```
ps aux | grep chrome
user    2212  0.0  0.0  12780   976 pts/0    S+   17:34   0:00 grep chrome
```

But `pgrep chrome` will return nothing.

In your case, `pgrep dockerd` will work.

Comment: `pgrep` matches on the process name unless you pass `-f` while `ps aux` shows the process arg lists. `pgrep` does an extended regexp match so `pgrep -f gnome-terminal` would still match on a process that runs `grep gnome-terminal`. Here you'd need `pgrep -fx /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server` to only match on processes whose full arg list is `/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -ef | grep -q "[d]ockerd"
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
then
      echo "dockerd is running"
else
      echo "dockerd is not running"
fi
```

Comment: That still matches on any process that has `dockerd` in its arg list or is running as the `dockerd` user